# Spring JDBC Transactional side effects

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I have a setup with 2 MySQL tables: Job and Summaries.

I am trying to check that the transaction management actually works as expected:

Following is the function:

```
@Transactional("mysqlTransactionManager")
public void sumLicenseDayUsage(List<LicenseUsage> usages)
{
        Job job = startJob();

        calculateDailyUsage(usages);

        updateJob(usages, job);
        completeJob(job);
}
```

I made sure that calculateDailyUsage() throws an exception. The different functions here are using MyBatis mappers for the actual SQL commands.

I expect that when the exception is thrown, no rows would be existing in the Job Table although they were created in startJob(). Still a row is always created and never rolled back.

I think i am using it by the book based on the doc but obviously i must be missing something.

Is there anything related to the fact i am using MyBatis? Or the fact that there are 2 tables and therefore 2 different mappers? IT doesn't look like it from the doc and from doing various testings.

Here is my XML configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="mysqlTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="mysqlBuilder" class="com.company.project.mysqlutils.EmbeddedMysqlDatabaseBuilder">
    <constructor-arg value="sql/create_sum_tables.sql"/>
</bean>


<bean id="billingDB" class="com.company.project.mysqlutils.EmbeddedMysqlDatabase" factory-bean="mysqlBuilder" factory-method="build"
      destroy-method="shutdown"/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="billingDB" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="billingDB" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:META-INF/mappers/mysql/**.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="billingDB" />
</bean>

<bean id="sumLicenseDayMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.company.project.sumtables.mappers.SumLicenseDayMapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobsMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.company.project.sumtables.mappers.JobsMapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I think this problem is overlooked by many people and can have enormous implications on the transaction scheme of applications

The problem turned out to be unrelated to how Spring manages the transaction. That worked actually perfectly.

However the behavior of the DB (MySQL in this case) is what caused the transaction to commit prematurely.

According to MySQL documentation at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html , certain DML and DDL statement cause an implicit commit of the current transaction.

This seems to be true for Oracle and Postgres as well based on their documentation and also this reported bug/feature by MySQL which states that Oracle behaves the same: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22857

In my case, the function calculateDailyUsage() had in it a "CREATE TABLE" statement, that caused an implicit commit and therefore made impossible the rollback of all the SQL statements that happened before it in case something went wrong after this statement.

To further explain how important is it, let suppose we design a billing application in which over billing is the worst sin, see below an example:

```
@Transactional("mysqlTransactionManager")
public void sumLicenseDayUsage(List<LicenseUsage> usages)
{
        insertBillingData();

        createIntermediateTable();

        summarizeData();
}
```

In the above if something goes wrong in summarizeData(), we definitely want the data inserted by insertBillingData() to be rolled back. But that actually will not happen because the intermediate statement createIntermediateTable() will actually commit the transaction and summarizeData() will be done in a different transaction. And that is very bad, this should be paid attention by designers because as it's common to create temporary table in the course of applications.

The way to overcome and how I solved it is by putting all the DDL/DML statements at the beginning of the function so that they are executed in their transaction and the rest of the function is done in another transaction that can be rolled back properly in case things go wrong, as follows:

```
@Transactional("mysqlTransactionManager")
public void sumLicenseDayUsage(List<LicenseUsage> usages)
{
        createIntermediateTable();

        insertBillingData();

        summarizeData();
}
```

Finally, one thing to keep in mind is that sometimes, the documentation is not accurate, for example MySQL doc states that a "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" does not do an implicit commit although it does after I tested it thoroughly.

Hope that helps.